# How to separate data in wordpress metabox?

Tags: checkbox, wordpress-theming, wordpress, meta-boxes

I just created a kind of long metabox using a tutorial at [wptuts](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reusable-custom-meta-boxes-part-1-intro-and-basic-fields/) but I am lost in two things:

1. The output of the metabox displays all data grouped (ex. in grouped checkboxes they are all in a whole even if I have different groups) and I'd like to grab the titles of each group and display them in different tables, divs or blocks.
2. Don't know how to display the saved data in the post, and also display it in separate blocks.

My code is this:

```
<?php

$prefix = 'dbt_';
$meta_box = array(
'id' => 'features',
'title' => 'Property Features',
'page' => 'post',
'context' => 'normal',
'priority' => 'high',
'fields' => array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Price (in USD)',
        'desc' => '',
        'id' => $prefix . 'text',
        'type' => 'text',
        'std' => ' '
    ),

      array(
        'name' => 'Price (in Mexican Peso)',
        'desc' => '',
        'id' => $prefix . 'text',
        'type' => 'text',
        'std' => ' '
    ),

    array(
        'name' => 'Address',
        'desc' => '',
        'id' => $prefix . 'textarea',
        'type' => 'textarea',
        'std' => ''
    ),

    array(
        'name' => 'Property for',
        'id' => $prefix . 'select',
        'type' => 'select',
        'options' => array('Sale', 'Rent', 'Vacational Rental')
    ),

    array(
        'name' => 'Area (m2)',
        'desc' => '',
        'id' => $prefix . 'text',
        'type' => 'text',
        'std' => ' '
    ),

    array(
        'name' => 'Area of terrain (m2)',
        'desc' => '',
        'id' => $prefix . 'text',
        'type' => 'text',
        'std' => ' '
    ),

    array(
        'name' => 'Number of rooms',
        'desc' => '',
        'id' => $prefix . 'text',
        'type' => 'text',
        'std' => ' '
    ),

    array(
        'name' => 'Number of bathrooms. Include half bathrooms (ex. 2 1/2)',
        'desc' => '',
        'id' => $prefix . 'text',
        'type' => 'text',
        'std' => ' '
    ),

    array(
        'name' => 'Service Bathroom',
        'id' => $prefix . 'checkbox',
        'type' => 'checkbox'
),

array(
        'name' => 'Furnished',
        'id' => $prefix . 'checkbox',
        'type' => 'checkbox'
),
array(  
        'label' => 'Property specs',  
        'desc'  => '',  
        'id'    => $prefix.'checkbox_group',  
        'type'  => 'checkbox_group',  
        'options' => array (  
        'one' => array (  
        'label' => 'Livingroom',  
        'value' => 'one'  
    ),  
        'two' => array (  
        'label' => 'Diningroom',  
        'value' => 'two'  
    ),  
        'three' => array (  
        'label' => 'Breackfast area',  
        'value' => 'three'  
    ), 

        'four' => array (  
        'label' => 'TV room',  
        'value' => 'four'  
    ),

        'five' => array (  
        'label' => 'Studio',  
        'value' => 'five'  
    ),

        'six' => array (  
        'label' => 'Integrated Kitchen',  
        'value' => 'six'  
    ),

        'seven' => array (  
        'label' => 'Laundry Room',  
        'value' => 'seven'  
    ),

        'eight' => array (  
        'label' => 'Service room',  
        'value' => 'eight'  
    ),

        'nine' => array (  
        'label' => 'jacuzzi',  
        'value' => 'nine'  
    ),

        'ten' => array (  
        'label' => 'terrace',  
        'value' => 'ten'  
    ),

        'eleven' => array (  
        'label' => 'balcony',  
        'value' => 'eleven'  
    ),

        'twelve' => array (  
        'label' => 'Warehouse',  
        'value' => 'twelve'  
    )
)  
),  


    array(  
        'label' => 'Installed',  
        'desc'  => '',  
        'id'    => $prefix.'checkbox_group',  
        'type'  => 'checkbox_group',  
        'options' => array (  
        'one' => array (  
        'label' => 'Air conditioner',  
        'value' => 'one'  
    ),  
        'two' => array (  
        'label' => 'Stationary gas',  
        'value' => 'two'  
    ),  
        'three' => array (  
        'label' => 'Water heater',  
        'value' => 'three'  
    ), 

        'four' => array (  
        'label' => 'Hurricain shutters or hurricain protection',  
        'value' => 'four'  
    ),

        'five' => array (  
        'label' => 'Telephone line',  
        'value' => 'five'  
    )
)  
),

    array(  
        'label' => 'Outdoors',  
        'desc'  => '',  
        'id'    => $prefix.'checkbox_group',  
        'type'  => 'checkbox_group',  
        'options' => array (  
        'one' => array (  
        'label' => 'Parking space',  
        'value' => 'one'  
    ),  
        'two' => array (  
        'label' => 'Garden',  
        'value' => 'two'  
    ),  
        'three' => array (  
        'label' => 'Pool',  
        'value' => 'three'  
    ), 

        'four' => array (  
        'label' => 'Tennis court',  
        'value' => 'four'  
    ),

        'five' => array (  
        'label' => 'Children playground',  
        'value' => 'five'  
    )
)  
),

    array(  
        'label' => 'Facilities',  
        'desc'  => '',  
        'id'    => $prefix.'checkbox_group',  
        'type'  => 'checkbox_group',  
        'options' => array (  
        'one' => array (  
        'label' => 'Spa',  
        'value' => 'one'  
    ),  
        'two' => array (  
        'label' => 'Gym',  
        'value' => 'two'  
    ),  
        'three' => array (  
        'label' => 'Party salon',  
        'value' => 'three'  
    ), 

        'four' => array (  
        'label' => 'Snack-bar',  
        'value' => 'four'  
    )

)  
),

    array(  
        'label' => 'Luxury Features',  
        'desc'  => '',  
        'id'    => $prefix.'checkbox_group',  
        'type'  => 'checkbox_group',  
        'options' => array (  
        'one' => array (  
        'label' => 'Clubhouse',  
        'value' => 'one'  
    ),  
        'two' => array (  
        'label' => 'Dock',  
        'value' => 'two'  
    ),  
        'three' => array (  
        'label' => 'Waterfront',  
        'value' => 'three'  
    ), 

        'four' => array (  
        'label' => 'Golf course',  
        'value' => 'four'  
    )


)  
)

)
);


add_action('admin_menu', 'mytheme_add_box');
// Add meta box
function mytheme_add_box() {
global $meta_box;
add_meta_box($meta_box['id'], $meta_box['title'], 'mytheme_show_box', $meta_box['page'],    $meta_box['context'], $meta_box['priority']);
}

// Callback function to show fields in meta box
function mytheme_show_box() {
global $meta_box, $post;
// Use nonce for verification
echo '<input type="hidden" name="mytheme_meta_box_nonce" value="', wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)), '" />';
echo '<div class="form-table">';
foreach ($meta_box['fields'] as $field) {
    // get current post meta data
    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);
    echo '<tr>',
            '<th style="width:20%"><label for="', $field['id'], '">', $field['name'], '</label></th>',
            '<td>';
    switch ($field['type']) {
        case 'text':
            echo '<input type="text" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" value="', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '" size="30" style="width:97%" />', '<br />', $field['desc'];
            break;
        case 'textarea':
            echo '<textarea name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" cols="60" rows="4" style="width:97%">', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '</textarea>', '<br />', $field['desc'];
            break;
        case 'select':
            echo '<select name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '">';
            foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
                echo '<option ', $meta == $option ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>', $option, '</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';
            break;
        case 'radio':
            foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
                echo '<input type="radio" name="', $field['id'], '" value="', $option['value'], '"', $meta == $option['value'] ? ' checked="checked"' : '', ' />', $option['name'];
            }
            break;
        case 'checkbox':
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '"', $meta ? ' checked="checked"' : '', ' />';
            break;


// checkbox_group  
case 'checkbox_group':  
foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {  
    echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$option['value'].'" name="'.$field['id'].'[]" id="'.$option['value'].'"',$meta && in_array($option['value'], $meta) ? ' checked="checked"' : '',' />  
            <label for="'.$option['value'].'">'.$option['label'].'</label><br />';  
}  
echo '<span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';  
break;    

    }
    echo     '</td><td>',
        '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
}

do_action('save_post', 'mytheme_save_data');
// Save data from meta box
function mytheme_save_data($post_id) {
global $meta_box;
// verify nonce
if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['mytheme_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
    return $post_id;
}
// check autosave
if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
    return $post_id;
}
// check permissions
if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
    if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id)) {
        return $post_id;
    }
} elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
    return $post_id;
}
foreach ($meta_box['fields'] as $field) {
    $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
    $new = $_POST[$field['id']];
    if ($new && $new != $old) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
    } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
        delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
    }
}
}

// check autosave
if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
return $post_id;
}
```

Comment: have you read this? http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reusable-custom-meta-boxes-part-4-using-the-data/

Comment: Hi Mark yeah Ive read it over and over but dont understand how to divide each block.

Answer (score 0):

```
$some_var = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'name_of_post_meta_data_here', true);

echo $some_var;
```

Does this help? Read the link Mark posted though.

**EDIT**

```
$some_var
```

Give it a name, like $currency, $address... this can be what you want.

```
get_post_meta($post->ID),
```

This means that it gets the meta data from the current post.

```
'name_of_post_meta_data_here', true);
```

This is where you say what it needs to put in the variable, so the custom meta boxes you created. The true is that it outputs a string, false for an array.

And than you can echo it out like:

```
<?php echo $some_var; ?>
```

I think you should check out [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com) or [Pods Framework](http://podsframework.org), they do exactly what you want and you need less PHP knowledge to handle it. I'm not a PHP hero so I can relate =)

Comment: I dont understand very well the vars yet. Maybe with that I can divide the blocks?

Comment: Can you please explain how to use the variables and if this will help me in displaying the blocks in backend and frontend?

Comment: Thanks Kortschot, I understand that I need to set variables for each field right? That code is for the output in the front end right? How can I show them in blocks in backend? sorry for being such a noob heh but I want to learn how to code it for the future, instead of using plugins. IM HUNGRY FOR KNOWLEDGE!